# Where is root directory in Drupal Acquia Desktop?

Tags: 7

With other systems it's www or htdocs, but what about with Acquia Desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your system; on Macs, it's in `home/Sites/acquia-drupal`.

To see where the files are for a site:

1. Open dev desktop.
2. Click settings.
3. Click the *Sites* tab.
4. Highlight the site you want to check and click *Edit*.
5. The site path will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks guys, for other newbies out there I made a screen capture.     http://www.vincentmoving.com/aquia-path.html

Answer (score 3):

Acquia desktop allows you to use any folder you wish as your root folder hence your site could be on the desktop, or documents. Use the import new site option in the settings tab to point to where drupal folder is located